# Was Suiryu or Garou who defeated Saitama in Virtual Reality?

Tags: one-punch-man

In OVA #4 season 2, Saitama is defeating playing Virtual Reality and Genos says the one who defeated might be able to defeat Saitama in real life. Then we see those moving to the finals of the competition are Suiryu and Garou.

Was Suiryu or Garou who defeated Saitama in Virtual Reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had observed, at the end the "female character" that beat Suiryu in an instant was infact King who comes to the Dias to collect the prize, he played with a usual Gaming controller and not a VR.

While walking either genos or king(dont remember) talks to themselves that a gaming controller is much faster compared to the VR.